# Avro schema for Json array

Tags: json, serialization, avro

Suppose I have following json:

```
[
   {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":1},
   {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":2},
   ...
]
```

What would be an appropriate avro schema for this array of objects?

Answer (score 2):

**[short answer]**
The appropriate avro schema for this array of objects would look like:

```
const type = avro.Type.forSchema({
  type: 'array',
  items: { type: 'record', fields:
   [ { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
     { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
     { name: 'user_id', type: 'int' } ]
  }
});
```

**[long answer]**

We can use Avro to help us build the above schema by given data object.
Let's use npm package "[avsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avsc)", which is "Pure JavaScript implementation of the Avro specification".
Since Avro can infer a value's schema we can use following trick to get schema by given data (unfortunately it seems can't show nested schemas, but we can ask twice - for top level structure (array) and then for array element):

```
// don't forget to install avsc
// npm install avsc
//
const avro = require('avsc');

// avro can infer a value's schema
const type = avro.Type.forValue([
   {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":1}
]);

const type2 = avro.Type.forValue(
   {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":1}
);


console.log(type.getSchema());
console.log(type2.getSchema());
```

Output:

```
{ type: 'array',
  items: { type: 'record', fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
{ type: 'record',
  fields:
   [ { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
     { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
     { name: 'user_id', type: 'int' } ] }
```

Now let's compose proper schema and try to use it to serialize object and then de-serialize it back!

```
const avro = require('avsc');
const type = avro.Type.forSchema({
  type: 'array',
  items: { type: 'record', fields:
   [ { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
     { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
     { name: 'user_id', type: 'int' } ]
  }
});
const buf = type.toBuffer([
   {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":1},
   {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":2}]); // Encoded buffer.

const val = type.fromBuffer(buf);
console.log("deserialized object: ", JSON.stringify(val, null, 4));  // pretty print deserialized result

var fs = require('fs');
var full_filename = "/tmp/avro_buf.dat";
fs.writeFile(full_filename, buf, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved to '" + full_filename + "'");
});
```

Output:

```
deserialized object:  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "some text",
        "user_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "some text",
        "user_id": 2
    }
]
The file was saved to '/tmp/avro_buf.dat'
```

We can even enjoy the compact binary representation of the above exercise:

```
hexdump -C /tmp/avro_buf.dat
00000000  04 02 12 73 6f 6d 65 20  74 65 78 74 02 02 12 73  |...some text...s|
00000010  6f 6d 65 20 74 65 78 74  04 00                    |ome text..|
0000001a
```

Nice, isn't she?-)

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your question, correct schema is

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "type": "array",
  "namespace": "com.hi.avro.model",
  "items": {
    "name": "NameDetails",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "text",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "user_id",
        "type": "int"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```