# Avro array using Apache Avro

Tags: java, avro

Actually my question is similar to answer shown in the link below (which shows serializing/desrializing using an avsc javascript library), but I will need a solution to serialize to avro and deserialize it using the apache avro for java instead...

[Avro schema for Json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040501/avro-schema-for-json-array)

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html

Data

```
[
 {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":1},
 {"id":1,"text":"some text","user_id":2},
 ...
]
```

Schema

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "type": "array",
  "namespace": "com.hi.avro.model",
  "items": {
    "name": "NameDetails",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "text",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "user_id",
        "type": "int"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You linked to the getting started guide which exists for just this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've proceed to read the API, and try it out on my code...

When I've created the post, I was trying hard to assign it to GenericRecord, which is not working. So I've posted the question because I am not clear of it.

In the end, instead of assigning the whole array to GenericRecord, I just proceed to use GenericArray and add GenericRecord to it

Below are snippet of the code

//to json

```
GenericArray record = new GenericDatumReader<GenericArray>(schema).read(null, binaryDecoder);

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
NoWrappingJsonEncoder jsonEncoder = new NoWrappingJsonEncoder(record.getSchema(), outputStream);
DatumWriter<GenericArray> writer = record instanceof SpecificRecord ?
            new SpecificDatumWriter<>(record.getSchema()) :
            new GenericDatumWriter<>(record.getSchema());
    writer.write(record, jsonEncoder);
    jsonEncoder.flush();
byte[] result = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

//to avro

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);
GenericDatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter(schema, genericData);
    
byte[] data;
    
List list = mapper.readValue(data, List.class);
    
GenericRecordBuilder record = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema.getElementType());
List<GenericData.Record> array = new ArrayList<>();

json.forEach(entry -> {
     //logic for reading GenericRecord for each of the list should be done here
     ...

     array.add(genericRecord);
});
    
writer.write(array, encoder);
     
encoder.flush();
     
byte[] result =  outputStream.toByteArray();
```